# Make mesa drivers become independent of previous nvidia installation

Tags: apt, nvidia, mesa, xvfb

I had **nvidia** driver installed on my *Ubuntu Server 16.04*. I need to run some app which needs OpenGL, but since machine is "headless" a virtual screen must be created.

I tried to do it with **Xvfb**, but app fails with **... unable to ... GLX ...** error. *Internet* at ~50 places says it's totally impossible to achieve a virtual screen with nvidia drivers installed.

So I uninstalled drivers with **apt remove --purge nvidia*** 
It didn't fix the problem so I removed nvidia's **.so** files present at **ldd /usr/bin/glxinfo** to *somehow* force **Xvfb** use **mesa**'s drivers, so now I have:

```
# ldd /usr/bin/glxinfo
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f37f7f50000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f37f7c16000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f37f784b000)
    libnvidia-tls.so.340.102 => not found
    libnvidia-glcore.so.340.102 => not found
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f37f7638000)
```

now **xvfb** and **glxinfo** fail with **error while loading shared libraries: libnvidia-tls.so.340.102: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory** error :(

**ldconfig** doesn't help as well as **apt install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dri xvfb mesa-utils**

Is there a way to get rid of remnants of nvidia's drivers? or make **xvfb** work along with presence of nvidia's OpenCL drivers?

Answer (score 0):

**sudo nvidia-uninstall** was a better way to uninstall driver than **apt remove --purge nvidia***. (driver was installed with **sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.102.run**)

After that, none of **glxinfo**, **Xvfb**, etc. wasn't working due to:

```
ldd /usr/lib/Xvfb
    ...
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd51461c000)
    libGL.so.1 => not found
    libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007fd514374000)
    ...
```

Was trying to fix it with different **apt install libgl1-mesa-dri ...** attempts, but seems like **ldconfig** automagically fixed that.

Now I can successfully run any OpenGL app with just **Xvfb-run -s "-screen 0 640x480x24" appname** without **... no GLX extension ...** problems! :)

Hope it will be helpful to someone trying to run OpenGL app on *headless* Ubuntu server with nvidia drivers previously installed.